# 'tailwindcss' is not recognized as an internal or external command

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css, postcss, autoprefixer

I have already pre installed tailwind css for my react library and added a script called build-css but run it, **npm run build-css** it gives me following error :
**'tailwindcss' is not recognized as an internal or external command**

**package.json** file

```
{
  "name": "react-firebase-authentication",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.11.9",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.2.3",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.6.0",
    "autoprefixer": "^9.8.8",
    "postcss": "^7.0.39",
    "react": "^17.0.1",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.1",
    "react-icons": "^4.3.1",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.1",
    "tailwindcss": "npm:@tailwindcss/postcss7-compat@^2.2.17",
    "web-vitals": "^0.2.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "build-css": "tailwindcss build src/styles.css -o public/styles.css",
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

**CMD** Error
[image: CMD ss]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Installing `postcss-cli` will help solves the problem.

```
npm install -D postcss postcss-cli
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Tailwind 2.x, you have to use Craco to configure it properly.  Please follow [this guideline](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/guides/create-react-app) from Tailwind documentation.